# Unsupported operand type(s) for 'X': 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, non-type

I'm currently working on a code and I'm getting this error.
Please explain what am I doing wrong in a simple way...help!

```
s=int(input('input random seed:'))
a=print('The first number is',format(random(50,56)))
b=print('The second number is',format(random(50,56)))
if (a*b)==c:
    print('Your answer is correct.')
```

Comment: `print` only print the argument to the console, it returns None

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines.

```
a = print('The first number is',format(random.randint(1,9)))
b = print('The second number is',format(random.randint(1,9)))
```

`print` function is used to print the values to the stdout and it does not return any value. A function in python that has no return value will implicitly return `None`, which means during the runtime the values of `a` and `b` are

```
a = None
b = None
```

So your `if` will evaluate to

```
if (None * None) == <YOUR_C_VALUE>:
```

Hence the error,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment says, on lines 4,5 and 6 of your code you're trying to assign the value of `print` to your variable, but the built-in `print` does not return a value.
What you want is:

```
a = random.randint(1,9)
```

then:

```
print('The first number is',format(a))
```

so that your code will do what your trying to achieve.
Note that after you get the input from command line for `c`, you'll have to convert it to `int` or whatever you want to use, because when you read raw input, it's read as string.

```
if (a*b)==int(c):
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python` print statement returns none so you cannot assign values there. You also don't require to conver the numbers into strings.

Try this:

```
import random
s=int(input('input random seed:'))
random.seed(s)
a= random.randint(1,9)
b= random.randint(1,9)
print(f'The first number is {a}') # f-string
print(f'The second number is {b}') # f-string

c=input('What is the product of two numbers? ')
print('Your answer is correct.') if (a*b)==int(c) else print('Your answer is wrong.')
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you are assigning with print statement that will return `None` in python

> a=print('The first number is',format(random.randint(1,9)))

try this:

```
import random
s=int(input('input random seed:'))
random.seed(s)
a=format(random.randint(1,9))
b=format(random.randint(1,9))
print('The first number is',a)
print('The second number is',b)
c=input('What is the product of two numbers?')
if (int(a)*int(b))==int(c):
    print('Your answer is correct.')
else:
    print('Your answer is wrong.')
```

Comment: Your method is incorrect. It returns `Your answer is wrong.` when `a = 3, b = 2, and c = 6`

Comment: @the myth Thanks for direction I had edited my answer